# Form HTML5 & PHP & Javascript tab

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the two code I have for one of my projects. The goal of this project is to have first page send information that opens into a new tab with the message from the information selected in the form. I am not fimilair with coding that much so my question is the following:

When I click submit the php page will open in a new tab showing the message and information. How do I or what direction should I look into to achieve the following tasks:

- click submit => open new tab with the php page
- click submit again => refreshes the php page tab that's already open with the updated information without opening up a new tab.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
     document.getElementById('senator').className = listindex;
   }
   
   </script>
      
   <style>
   optgroup {
     display: none;
   }

   select.agriculture 
   optgroup.agriculture
      {
     display: block;
   }
   
   div#header{
   padding: 1px;
   color: yellow;
   padding-left: 9px;
   background-color: #000080;
   }
   
   .room130{
   padding: 9px;
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   }
 
   </style>
 </head>
 
<body>

 <div class="header" id="header">
 <h1>test header</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="room130">
 <h3>Room 130</h3>
 <form target="_blank" action = "room130.php" method="POST">
  <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Committee:
   <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Select Committee</option>
    <option value="agriculture">AGRICULTURE</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
  Individual:
   <select name="senator" id="senator">
    <option value="">Select individual</option>
     <optgroup class="agriculture">
      <option value="the chair">THE CHAIR</option>
      <option value="the presenter">THE PRESENTER</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
      <option value="test">test</option>
     </optgroup>
   </select>
  </div>
```

PHP:

```html
<html>
 <header>
  <title>Room 130</title>


  <style>
   div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    
    background-color: #000080;
    color: white;
   }
   
  </style>
 </header>

<body>

 <div class="message" id="message">
  <h2>Message <?php echo $_POST["senator"]; ?>. Thank you. </h2>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you'd like to pass the variable to the next page?

Comment: @scoopzilla yes  and to refresh the page with new information without creating a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second file `room130.php` contains next title :

```
<title>Room 130</title>
```

You can use that title as target in the `<form` of your first file :

```
                 ▼
<form target="Room 130" action = "room130.php" method="POST">
```

The first time the `<form` is submitted the target will **open a new tab**, if the same form is submitted again **it will not open a new tab**, instead it will **refresh** the already opened tab because it contains the title "Room 130".

Answer (score 0):

> - click submit => open new tab with the php page

Setting the `target` attribute on the form element already does that.

> - click submit again => refreshes the php page tab that's already open with the updated information without opening up a new tab.

Use a different name than `_blank` for the target. `_blank` *always* opens a new tab, whereas if the target attribute is pointing at any other named tab, it will re-use that one when you re-submit the form.

There are a few "reserved" tab names besides `_blank`, such as `_self` (explicitly open in current tab), `_parent` (next level up in any frame environment) and `_top` (top-most frame). So choose a tab name yourself, something that fits the "meaning" of what happens in the new tab maybe. It doesn't have to start with an underscore - that is rather a convention for those reserved ones - so something along the lines of `target="result"`